# Questions regarding Quartz.net

Tags: quartz.net

Please help me clear the following doubts.

1) I am using the GetScheduler() method to assign the scheduler to a local variable. Does the scheduler automatically starts when GetScheduler() called? If yes,how does the scheduler starts if there is a persistent job available. Who is calling GetScheduler then?

2) Is storing the scheduler in a local variable(inside a function) safe?

2) How can i configure the quartz.net properties such as thread pool size,database configuration,etc.

Awaiting your valuable reply.

Thanks in advance,

John.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you using to work with the Quartz scheduler, you have tagged this post with both the Java and .Net versions.

The basic approach is to construct the scheduler factory and obtain a scheduler instance from that object. After this create a trigger and define the Job.

Basically the trigger says when to run the job and the job object is the code which performs an action.

I highly recommend reading through the tutorial code on the relevant Quartz website, it answers your above questions. If that doesnt help then post back with some sample code.